# Need to get the position of mouse pointer when release

Tags: xcode, cocoa, ikimageview

I am using IKImageView for the functionalities of Image.

```
- (IBAction)switchToolMode: (id)sender
{
    // switch the tool mode...

    NSInteger newTool;

    if ([sender isKindOfClass: [NSSegmentedControl class]])
        newTool = [sender selectedSegment];
    else
        newTool = [sender tag];

    switch (newTool)
    {
        case 0:
            [_imageView setCurrentToolMode: IKToolModeMove];
            break;
        case 1:
            [_imageView setCurrentToolMode: IKToolModeSelect];
            break;
        case 2:
            [_imageView setCurrentToolMode: IKToolModeCrop];
            break;
        case 3:
            [_imageView setCurrentToolMode: IKToolModeRotate];
            break;
        case 4:
            [_imageView setCurrentToolMode: IKToolModeAnnotate];
            break;

    }
}
```

After the `[_imageView setCurrentToolMode: IKToolModeAnnotate];` called i need to get the current mouse position (After drawing the shape). `IKToolModeAnnotate` is default function so i am not able to find where the control goes next.

Can anybody solve my problem.

Answer (score 1):

From `NSApplication`you always can get the last respectively current event by calling `[NSApp currentEvent]`. From that you can extract the mouse location.

Alternatively you get the location via `[NSWindow mouseLocationOutsideOfEventStream]`. I recommend to read up on `NSEvent`so you know the differences between these locations, which is the coordinate system used for the point. [See also NSEvent documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSEvent_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSEvent/mouseLocation) .